# Fixing a directX function which gets the video length in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, directx

I have found a function which invokes `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback` to get the length of a video file.

Here is that code:

```
`Private Function GetVideoInformation(ByVal videoFilePath As String) As VideoInfo
    Try
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(videoFilePath) Then
            Dim videoToGetInfoOn As Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video
            videoToGetInfoOn = New Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video(videoFilePath)
            Dim atpf As Double = videoToGetInfoOn.AverageTimePerFrame
            Dim vidSize As New Size
            vidSize = videoToGetInfoOn.Size

        Dim thisVideoInfo As New VideoInfo
            thisVideoInfo.videoWidth = vidSize.Width
            thisVideoInfo.videoHeight = vidSize.Height
        thisVideoInfo.videoDuration = videoToGetInfoOn.Duration
        If videoToGetInfoOn.Duration > 0 Then
            defaultLength = videoToGetInfoOn.Duration
        End If

        If atpf > 0 Then
            thisVideoInfo.videoFps = 1 / atpf
        Else
            thisVideoInfo.videoFps = 0
        End If

        Return thisVideoInfo
    Else
        Throw New Exception("Video File Not Found" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & videoFilePath)

        Return Nothing
    End If
   Catch ex as Exception
     msgbox(ex.message)
   End Try
End Function`
```

I have a timer that calls this function once on 2 seconds to check many videos, and the app works fine for the first 10 videos or so. After that, it throws

```
"Error in application"
```

message instead.

Comment: Check your memory in taskmanager.  Does the Video or VideoInfo object have a dispose method. Try calling them. They may have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, things from DirectShow/DirectX MUST be disposed of in the way the docs require or this sort of thing happens.  Here, you are creating `videoToGetInfoOn` objects but never releasing them.

You need to explicitly release all the resources you and it allocated with `videoToGetInfoOn = Nothing` before your procedure exits. Try that.

I will add that `MediaInfo.DLL` can be used to get **everything** from a media file without the overhead of Dx.  There is a commandline version that you might be able to read from reading stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

The code needs a dispose method.

Here is the final code:

```
`Private Function GetVideoInformation(ByVal videoFilePath As String) As VideoInfo
    Try
      If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(videoFilePath) Then
        Dim videoToGetInfoOn As Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video
        videoToGetInfoOn = New Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video(videoFilePath)
        Dim atpf As Double = videoToGetInfoOn.AverageTimePerFrame
        Dim vidSize As New Size
        vidSize = videoToGetInfoOn.Size

    Dim thisVideoInfo As New VideoInfo
        thisVideoInfo.videoWidth = vidSize.Width
        thisVideoInfo.videoHeight = vidSize.Height
    thisVideoInfo.videoDuration = videoToGetInfoOn.Duration
    If videoToGetInfoOn.Duration > 0 Then
        defaultLength = videoToGetInfoOn.Duration
    End If

    If atpf > 0 Then
        thisVideoInfo.videoFps = 1 / atpf
    Else
        thisVideoInfo.videoFps = 0
    End If

    videoToGetInfoOn.Dispose() 'this line here needed to be added
    Return thisVideoInfo
Else
    Throw New Exception("Video File Not Found" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & videoFilePath)

    Return Nothing
End If
  Catch ex as Exception
     msgbox(ex.message)
  End Try
End Function`
```